# Pandas Dataframe does not include column from PostgreSQL Query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

Pandas dataframe doesn't include a column from a query no matter how I cast the value. Below is the part of the query that returns the desired column/value:

```
(select string_agg(all_them.splc, ',') from (select sub.stat_details::json->> 'event_splc' as splc, sub.actual_created_at from pub.shipt_stat as sub where sub.shipt_id = s.id and sub.stat_details::json->> 'event_splc' is not null order by sub.created_at) as all_them)::text as sub_route
```

I expect the value to look like this:

```
318200000,318200000,318200000,318345000,318345000,315907000,315907000,365115000,365115000,365540000,365540000,366650000,369526000,369282000,387764000,392200000,392200000,392415000,564618000,565630000,565630000,565657000,566793000,566793000,566786000,566786000,566786000
```

The dataframe loads every other field from the select statement except this one column. Do dataframe columns have a character limit? Should I be casting the value as something else? Dbeaver compiles, runs, and returns the value as a string.

Ultimately, my goal is to create a code for each unique string:

```
e2e['sub_route_cd'] = e2e['sub_route'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your table?

Comment: It is a huge table and not sure I could anonymize (spelling?) it all...this is a project for work and I have come here because not many of the developers have experience with sqlalchemy and pandas. Is there something else I can provide that would help something more specific you are thinking could be causing an issue?